# iOS Vertical Swipe is performed as Horizontal Swipe in Appium 1.7.2

Tags: java, appium-ios

I am using the below code to swipe vertically in my iOS real device automation project, but during execution it is actually performing horizontal swipe.

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
int startx = size.width / 2;
driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 2000);
```

Can anyone please let me know if I have done anything wrong?

Xcode version: 8.3.2
iOS version: 10.2
Appium Version: 1.7.2

Comment: I have faced same issue.In my case,the problem was the application was taking the coordinates from portrait mode even though it was in landscape mode.So please check coordinates in both portrait mode & landscape mode whether they are same or not.

Comment: @Sneha Shinde Can you please elaborate more on this? How to check the co-ordinates in portrait and landscape mode? And what fix you have given to solve the issue?

Comment: when you are taking x & y coordinates of element in portrait mode check same coordinates are available for that element in landscape mode.because when you are changing the rotation may be coordinates are different.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.swipe` is **deprecated** in *Appium Java client*. You should stop using it.

For doing **vertical swipe on iOS** Appium exposes [mobile:swipe](http://appium.io/test/fixtures/sample.html#mobile-swipe) and if you need to set direction - [mobile:scroll](http://appium.io/test/fixtures/sample.html#mobile-scroll)

Python:

```
driver.execute_script('mobile: scroll', {'direction': 'down'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this one, and it works both ways, vertical & horizontal:

```
public enum DIRECTION {
    DOWN, UP, LEFT, RIGHT;
}


public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction) {
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;

        case UP:
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;

        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(startX, endY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;

    }
}
```